# How to find the equation of a plane with two identical lines?

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus

How do you find the equation of a plane with two identical lines?

Example: In each case, determine whether or not the given pair of lines intersect. Also, find all planes containing the pair of lines.
$$\langle x,y,z \rangle = \langle 3,2,-2 \rangle + s \langle -2,-2,2 \rangle, \quad \langle x,y,z \rangle = \langle 2,1,-1 \rangle + s \langle 1,1,-1 \rangle.$$

I equated the two lines together but didn't get a sufficient value to continue with the problem. NOTE: This not an assignment problem it's just for practice before I start multivariable calculus.

Comment: You may need to change the parameters on the lines to two different letters. [For each line the parameters take on values independently of each other]

Comment: Since you're new here, I'm going to remind you that you should either ask follow-up questions when someone posts an answer if necessary and then accept the answer when you're not satisfied. Otherwise, the post keeps appearing as unanswered.

Answer (score 3):

You're right that the two lines are identical. They have the same direction, and you can see that $(3,2,-2) = (2,1,-1) + (1,1,-1)$, so every point on the first line is on the second line (and vice versa).

There are infinitely many planes passing through a given line. The normal vector $\vec A$ of the plane must be orthogonal to  $(1,1,-1)$ and the plane must pass through the point $(2,1,-1)$. So, for any vector $\vec A$ satisfying $\vec A \cdot (1,1,-1) = 0$, the plane
$$\vec A \cdot (x-1,y-1,z+1) = 0$$
contains the line.

P.S. I suspect that the computer software that generated this particular exercise was badly programmed by a human somewhere along the way.

Comment: Given the phrasing of the question ("find all planes containing the pair of lines"), I think the question designer did intend to sometimes include this degenerate case.